# How to get the children of the $(this) selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a layout similar to this:

```
<div id="..."><img src="..."></div>
```

and would like to use a jQuery selector to select the child `img` inside the `div` on click.

To get the `div`, I've got this selector:

```
$(this)
```

How can I get the child `img` using a selector?

Answer (score 2978, accepted):

The jQuery constructor accepts a 2nd parameter called [`context`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) which can be used to override the context of the selection.

```
jQuery("img", this);
```

Which is the same as using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) like this:

```
jQuery(this).find("img");
```

If the imgs you desire are **only** direct descendants of the clicked element, you can also use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children):

```
jQuery(this).children("img");
```

Comment: for what it's worth: 
    jQuery("img", this)
is internally converted into:
    jQuery(this).find("img")

So the second is ever so slightly faster. :)

Answer (score 494):

You could also use

```
$(this).find('img');
```

which would return all `img`s that are descendants of the `div`

Comment: In general cases, it seems like `$(this).children('img')` would be better. e.g. `<div><img src="..." /><div><img src="..." /></div></div>` because presumably the user wants to find 1st-level imgs.

Answer (score 148):

If you need to get the first `img` that's down exactly one level, you can do

```
$(this).children("img:first")
```

Answer (score 82):

If your DIV tag is immediately followed by the IMG tag, you can also use:

```
$(this).next();
```

Comment: .next() is really fragile, unless you can always guarantee the element will be the next element, it's better to use a different method.  In this case, the IMG is a descendant, not a sibling, of the div.

Answer (score 78):

The *direct* children is

```
$('> .child-class', this)
```

Answer (score 58):

You can find all `img` element of parent div like below

```
$(this).find('img') or $(this).children('img')
```

If you want a specific `img` element you can write like this

```
$(this).children('img:nth(n)')  
// where n is the child place in parent list start from 0 onwards
```

Your div contains only one `img` element. So for this below is right

```
 $(this).find("img").attr("alt")
                  OR
  $(this).children("img").attr("alt")
```

But if your div contain more `img` element like below

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <img src="test.png" alt="3">
    <img src="test.png" alt="4">
</div>
```

then you can't use upper code to find alt value of second img element. So you can try this:

```
 $(this).find("img:last-child").attr("alt")
                   OR
 $(this).children("img:last-child").attr("alt")
```

This example shows a general idea that how you can find actual objects within the parent object.
You can use classes to differentiate your child's object. That is easy and fun. i.e.

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <img class='first' src="test.png" alt="3">
    <img class='second' src="test.png" alt="4">
</div>
```

You can do this as below :

```
 $(this).find(".first").attr("alt")
```

and more specific as:

```
 $(this).find("img.first").attr("alt")
```

You can use find or children as above code. For more visit Children http://api.jquery.com/children/ and Find http://api.jquery.com/find/.
See example http://jsfiddle.net/lalitjs/Nx8a6/

Answer (score 37):

Ways to refer to a child in jQuery. I summarized it in the following jQuery:

```
$(this).find("img"); // any img tag child or grandchild etc...   
$(this).children("img"); //any img tag child that is direct descendant 
$(this).find("img:first") //any img tag first child or first grandchild etc...
$(this).children("img:first") //the first img tag  child that is direct descendant 
$(this).children("img:nth-child(1)") //the img is first direct descendant child
$(this).next(); //the img is first direct descendant child
```

Answer (score 32):

Without knowing the ID of the DIV I think you could select the IMG like this:

```
$("#"+$(this).attr("id")+" img:first")
```

Comment: this probably actually works but it's kinda the Rube Goldberg answer :)

Answer (score 31):

Try this code:

```
$(this).children()[0]
```

Comment: @rémy: That's not even valid syntax. (Took all of 2 years for anyone to notice...)

Answer (score 25):

You can use either of the following methods:

**1 find():**

```
$(this).find('img');
```

**2 children():**

```
$(this).children('img');
```

Answer (score 22):

jQuery's `each` is one option:

```
<div id="test">
    <img src="testing.png"/>
    <img src="testing1.png"/>
</div>

$('#test img').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use [Child Selecor](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to reference the child elements available within the parent.

```
$(' > img', this).attr("src");
```

And the below is if you don't have reference to `$(this)` and you want to reference `img` available within a `div` from other function.

```
 $('#divid > img').attr("src");
```

Answer (score 13):

Also this should work:

```
$("#id img")
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a functional code, you can run it (it's a simple demonstration).

When you click the DIV you get the image from some different methods, in this situation "this" is the DIV.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // When you click the DIV, you take it with "this"
  $('#my_div').click(function() {
    console.info('Initializing the tests..');
    console.log('Method #1: '+$(this).children('img'));
    console.log('Method #2: '+$(this).find('img'));
    // Here, i'm selecting the first ocorrence of <IMG>
    console.log('Method #3: '+$(this).find('img:eq(0)'));
  });
});
```

```css
.the_div{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_div" class="the_div">
  <img src="...">
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

You may have 0 to many `<img>` tags inside of your `<div>`.

To find an element, use a `.find()`.

To keep your code safe, use a `.each()`.

Using `.find()` and `.each()` together prevents null reference errors in the case of 0 `<img>` elements while also allowing for handling of multiple `<img>` elements.

```js
// Set the click handler on your div
$("body").off("click", "#mydiv").on("click", "#mydiv", function() {

  // Find the image using.find() and .each()
  $(this).find("img").each(function() {
  
        var img = this;  // "this" is, now, scoped to the image element
        
        // Do something with the image
        $(this).animate({
          width: ($(this).width() > 100 ? 100 : $(this).width() + 100) + "px"
        }, 500);
        
  });
  
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 50px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">
  <img src="" width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // When you click the DIV, you take it with "this"
  $('#my_div').click(function() {
    console.info('Initializing the tests..');
    console.log('Method #1: '+$(this).children('img'));
    console.log('Method #2: '+$(this).find('img'));
    // Here, i'm selecting the first ocorrence of <IMG>
    console.log('Method #3: '+$(this).find('img:eq(0)'));
  });
});
```

```css
.the_div{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_div" class="the_div">
  <img src="...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your img is exactly first element inside div then try

```
$(this.firstChild);
```

```js
$( "#box" ).click( function() {
  let img = $(this.firstChild);
  console.log({img});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/300/150"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With native javascript you can use

if you've more than one image tag then use

`this.querySelectorAll("img")`

if only one image tag then us

`this.querySelector("img")`

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 $(this).find('img');
</script>
```