# Jquery $(this) Child Selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, children

I'm using this:

```
jQuery('.class1 a').click( function() {
  if ($(".class2").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".class2").slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    $(".class2").slideUp();
  }
});
```

On page structure:

```
<div class="class1">
  <a href="...">text</a>
  <div class="class2">text</div>
</div>
```

It only works when you don't have multiple class1/class2 sets like:

```
<div class="class1">
  <a href="...">text</a>
  <div class="class2">text</div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
  <a href="...">text</a>
  <div class="class2">text</div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
  <a href="...">text</a>
  <div class="class2">text</div>
</div>
```

How do I change the initial jquery code so that it only effects class2 under the class1 that was clicked? I tried recommendations from [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/jquery-this-selector-and-children) but haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The best way with the HTML you have would probably be to use the [`next`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next#expr) function, like so:

```
var div = $(this).next('.class2');
```

Since the click handler is happening to the `<a>`, you could also traverse up to the parent DIV, then search down for the second DIV. You would do this with a combination of [`parent`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent#expr) and [`children`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children#expr). This approach would be best if the HTML you put up is not exactly like that and the second DIV could be in another location relative to the link:

```
var div = $(this).parent().children('.class2');
```

If you wanted the "search" to not be limited to immediate children, you would use [`find`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr) instead of `children` in the example above.

Also, it is always best to prepend your class selectors with the tag name if at all possible. ie, if only `<div>` tags are going to have those classes, make the selector be `div.class1`, `div.class2`.

Answer (score 9):

In the click event "this" is the a tag that was clicked

```
jQuery('.class1 a').click( function() {
   var divToSlide = $(this).parent().find(".class2");
   if (divToSlide.is(":hidden")) {
      divToSlide.slideDown("slow");
   } else {
      divToSlide.slideUp();
   }
});
```

There's multiple ways to get to the div though you could also use .siblings, .next etc

Answer (score 7):

This is a lot simpler with [.slideToggle()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle):

```
jQuery('.class1 a').click( function() {
  $(this).next('.class2').slideToggle();
});
```

EDIT: made it .next instead of .siblings

http://www.mredesign.com/demos/jquery-effects-1/

You can also add cookie's to remember where you're at...

http://c.hadcoleman.com/2008/09/jquery-slide-toggle-with-cookie/

Comment: Thanks for the slideToggle reference to simplify. I had them separated before only because I was playing with fadeOut in the else

Answer (score 5):

http://jqapi.com/
Traversing--> Tree Traversal --> Children