# Jquery $(this) Child Selector Not working for some unknown reason

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, children

I am trying to show/hide the child class when parent is hovered. I have multiple class set like in [Jquery $(this) Child Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841553/jquery-this-child-selector).

for some unknown reason it is not working.

What I have is

```
<div class="parentitem">
    <div class="childitem">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also

```
$("div.childitem").css({visibility: "hidden"});

$("div.parentitem").mouseenter(function(){
    $("div.childitem").css({visibility: "visible"});
});

$("div.parentitem").mouseleave(function(){
    $("div.childitem").css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

This works but all the children are affected. What I wanted is to affect only particular div and its child

I tried to use

```
$(this).children("div.childitem").css({visibility: "visible"});

$(this).parent().children("div.childitem").css({visibility: "visible"});

$(this).next("div.childitem").css({visibility: "visible"});
```

None of this is working for some reason.

Can somebody point me where I went wrong.

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: what is `$(this)`, the div with id `parentitem`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$("div.childitem").css({visibility: "hidden"});

$("div.parentitem").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.childitem').css({visibility: 'visible'});
});

$("div.parentitem").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.childitem').css({visibility: 'hidden'});
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NyS6z/).

Comment: Thats what I was going to suggest :)

Comment: It works for me, on the JS Fiddle demo that I posted. Do you have something else going on in your page? Have you checked your JavaScript console for any errors?

Comment: I have seen demo and it is working but in my page it's not. Javascript console doesn't also show any error. Thanks... I have to check it little bit deeper.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$(this).find("div.childitem")` instead of `$(this).children("div.childitem")`.

`children()` finds the *immediate* children only, while `find()` searches among all children, i.e. the children's children and their children and so on.

If that still doesn't work, I suggest to anaylze the order in which all related event handlers are called. Might be that the result of the mouseenter event handlers is instantly undone by some other event handler.

In Chrome or with Firebug in Firefox you can log to the console. E.g. for Chrome it's `console.log(text_or_object)`.

Comment: Try to debug your event handlers, i.e. try to understand in which order they're called and what they're *actually* doing to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you'll need:

```
$("div.parentitem").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find("div.childitem").css({visibility: "visible"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $(this) as the selector *context* ie

```
$("div.childitem",$(this))
```

Though there is probably a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 0):

This might be interesting: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DrkwB/2/

I just modified an existing example to accommodate multiple content areas and then the particular parent that is hovered on, its child element is hidden or shown accordingly.