# strip all <img> tags within a div

Tags: jquery, image

I have a jcycle plugin on a number of divs which are testimonials. Basically I don't want to show the `<img>` tag in the testimonial viewed in a block on the front page but rather I do want it to show on another page. So I want to add some jQuery or another method that strips the img tags for the front page display.

How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#div img").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#div img').remove();
```

Comment: first answer was edited to the correct answer (read: mine) after I submitted mine :D oh well

Answer (score 0):

`$('.testimonial img').hide();` to hide the images within each matching div.

Comment: I want to remove them from the markup rather than hide, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think this can be relevant for you: [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/jquery-this-selector-and-children)

Answer (score -1):

Alternate:

```
$('#div').find('img').remove();
```