# jQuery fade content within a div

Tags: jquery

Hey there, so far i have this, it toggles my footer down and up, but i want the content of the footer to fade out and new content fade in when it's toggled down.
I can't for the life of me work it out, please help! - thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#footertab').toggle(function() {
    $('#footer').animate({
      bottom: '-=120'
    }, 1000);
  },function() {
    $('#footer').animate({
      bottom: '+=120'
    }, 1000);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the children() function:

```
$("#footer").children().fadeOut();
```

Comment: Thanks, Where abouts should i drop this into my code? I'm confused by the toggle.

Comment: ThankYou Bertrand Marron thats brilliant, although I'm having another problem, am I able to define which .children to fade out rather than all of them, and is it possible to fade in another div, in other words... I'm trying to fade out 2 divs, and fade in 2 different div's when its down. so the content when down is different t the content when up.

Comment: Yes, instead of going .children() do .children("selector")

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ugugo3/3/ I've tried it, I've managed to fade the original div out, but I can't get the rest to work, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the 2nd parameter of the jQuery selector - "Selector Context", which is a great shorthand for searching for elements within a context.

*The following would add a class of 'bar' to the span contained within a clicked div:*

```
$('div.foo').click(function() {
  $('span', this).addClass('bar');
});
```

(from api documentation)

> Internally, selector context is
>   implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to
>   $(this).find('span').

*Further Reading..*

- [jQuery API Doc on "Selector Context"](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context)
- [Previous Stack Overflow Question about jQuery & Chilren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children#answer-306904)

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, but i'm failing to understand this, I'm a very basic jQuery user, As I understand i'm assigning a class to the div with the id of 'foo', are you suggesting that I can assign a class to all the div that i want to .fadeOut() ?

Comment: In the above example, it actually "binds" or attaches a click event listener to every <div> which has a class of "foo".

Now, when a <div class="foo"> is clicked, it will add the class "bar" to any spans INSIDE THE CLICKED DIV, not all divs.

Make more sense?