# How to get child elements of $self, jquery is OK

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#cont > fieldset').each(
function(index){
        var $self = $(this);
        // Here how to get child elements? How to write this selector?
        //$('$self > div') ?? this seems does not work.


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$self.find("div"); // return all descendant divs
```

or:

```
$self.children("div"); // return immediate child divs
```

depending on whether you want *immediate* children or *any* descendants.

You can even do this to get immediate child divs, but `children` is prettier :

```
$self.find(">div");
```

Comment: This will find descendants, not just children.

Comment: Thanks David, was writing that in.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method in jQuery. This will get direct children of the element, e.g.:

```
$self.children('div') // returns divs that are direct children
```

You can also use the similar [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method if you need to go deeper than one level.

```
$self.find('div') // returns divs that are direct children, or children of children
```

Also, you can select using `$self` as the context, like:

```
$('div', $self) //returns all divs within $self
```

Answer (score 1):

using [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
 $(this).children('div')
```

or
using [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find('div');
```

look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method, to get all immediate children of self.

```
var children = $self.children();
```