# $(this) with child and pseudo selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the selection below, is there any way to make this selection work with *$(this)*?

(select the second div child of .container)

```
$(".container div:eq(2)").width();
```

Comment: Does `$(this)` refer to `$('.container')`?

Comment: yes, this refers to the $('.container')

Comment: @Thomas , whatever html element attached to the event , $(this) is nothing but that element...reference

Comment: @Thomas , if you want to get parent , you can use .parent()

Comment: :eq(2) is almost the same to :nth-child(3) why are you suggesting going the opposite way?

Comment: @Thomas , can you please post the click handler , or whatever event handler code and html also//

Comment: there is no click hander... There is no event it's for a plugin function. Need something similar to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".container").each(function(){
    $(this).find("div:eq(2)"); // if its not a direct child
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there already is fine. Why do you want to use `$(this)`? You would use `$(this)` as an example, in a function:

```
$(".container div:eq(2)").click(function() {
    if( $(this).width > 100 ) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I am piecing together a "plugin" that involves selecting $(".container div:eq(2)").width(), trying to think of a way to pass in the outermost div as a variable and I need to use $(this).

Comment: What about using `$(this).parent()`?

Comment: :eq(2) is almost the same to :nth-child(3) why are you suggesting going the opposite way?

Comment: @Thomas it depends which click hander you attached, if you attach parent if we  can traverser forward ,if you attach child you will traverse opposite direction...

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
$(this).find("div:eq(2)").width()
```

or:

```
$("div:eq(2)", this).width()
```

?

BTW that returns the width of the *third* div descendant from `this` (which unlike div:nth-child(2) may or may not have two siblings before it, :eq() refers to the position in the matching pseudo-array, not in the DOM)