# Jquery add pointer to nav

Tags: jquery, css, sprite

I have a problem. Everytime I mouseover my list (doesn't matter which list item it is) the class .hover is added across the whole list. So is class .over.  I realize I am adding those through jquery but how can have jquery only addclass to one list anchor only rather than all of them across the board.

```
$('.menuContainer li a').append('<span></span>');

$(".menuContainer li a").mouseover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass("over");
            $('.menuContainer li a span').addClass('hover');
        return false;
});
$(".menuContainer li a").mouseout(
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("over");
            $('.menuContainer li a span').removeClass('hover');
        return false;
});

<div class="menuContainer">
<ul>
 <li class="1">
<a href="#">list item<span></span></a>
</li>
 <li class="2">
<a href="#">list item<span></span></a>
</li>
 <li class="3">
<a href="#">list item<span></span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My goal is to have the class .hover with a background image that will be a pointer to emphasize what is currently being moused over.

Comment: Just for clarity (since you have two good answers below) it's important to remember that jQuery matches ALL elements by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you want to select the span of the **current** anchor, you should use the following notation `$("span", this)` as the selector... looks like this:

```
$('.menuContainer li a').append('<span></span>');

$(".menuContainer li a").mouseover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass("over");
            $("span", this).addClass('hover');
        return false;
});
$(".menuContainer li a").mouseout(
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("over");
            $("span", this).removeClass('hover');
        return false;
});
```

As pointed out in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children) it performs a .find() within the specified selector element.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Beat me to it by 30 seconds ;)

Comment: Happens to me all the time, I have to say SO is an awesome way to improve typing speed :P

Comment: Yeah, I was going to use the .find() operator in my answer, but that enhanced notation is dope.

Comment: I know right, I only came across that post, and that notation a few days ago... never had a need for it before, but now I use it like mad.

Answer (score 2):

[Damien-at-SF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452348/damien-at-sf) 's answer is fair enough. But I'm thinking it would just add another work.

why not leave your codes as it is and play with the `css`.
if you want to style the `<span>`'s, do it like this,

```
.menuContainer li a.over span { .... }
.menuContainer li a.over span.hover { .... }
```

and on my experience, it is best to add/ remove class (to something like this situation) where you can have siblings relation (in this situation, the `<li>`'s ).

your codes will then be shorten to something like this,

```
$(".menuContainer li a").mouseover(
    function() {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("over").find('span').addClass('hover')
        .end().siblings().removeClass("over").find('span').removeClass('hover');
}).append('<span></span>');
```