# Selecting a child image of a clicked on element in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So I have the HTML like this:

```
<p class="agendaNav"><img class="rightArrow" src="/images/arrowright.png"> WEEK AT A GLANCE</p>
<p class="agendaNav"><img class="rightArrow" src="/images/arrowright.png"> MONDAY</p>
<p class="agendaNav"><img class="rightArrow" src="/images/arrowright.png"> TUESDAY</p>
```

In Jquery I want to change the src attribute from ArrowRight.png to arrowdown.png when it is clicked.

How would I do that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('.agendaNav').click(function(event){

    $(this).('.rightArrow').attr('src', '/images/arrowdown.png');
});
```

What am I doing Wrong?

Oh and I only want to change the Arrow of the clicked on element, not every single one.

Comment: There is another question [$(this) selector and children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children) might be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You syntax is wrong.

after the `.` you need to use the name of a method

```
$(this).find('.rightArrow').attr('src', '/images/arrowdown.png');
```

Alternatively you can use this syntax

```
$('.rightArrow', this).attr('src', '/images/arrowdown.png');
```

which uses the `this` as the context for where to search in.

reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1