# Reference an element of $(this) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, this, each

I'm iterating through a series of elements in jQuery (intentionally).

So basically I want something like this, but with the correct syntax:

```
$(".sonicrow").each(function() {
    $(this + 'somediv').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Obviously this is some kind of object/string mishmash. What would the correct syntax be for accessing the specific somediv within the this object?

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".sonicrow").each(function() {
    $('somediv', this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Where the second parameter is the "context" of the selector. Of cause your `somediv` have to be `.somediv` if it´s a class or `#somediv` if it´s an id.

This question is related to [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children) which also contains this answer

```
...
    $(this).find('somediv').css(...)
...
```

According to [jQuery context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) `$(selector, context)` is implemented with `$(context).find(selector)`.

Comment: but isn't `$(this).find('somediv').css(...)` slower than the first one??

Comment: @experimentX see my latest addition to the answer. According to jQuery documentation, they are equivalent :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".sonicrow").each(function() {
    $(this).find('somediv').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".sonicrow").each(function() {
    $(this).find('.somediv').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

you can do like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm:**

HTML structure is a tree structure. So when you refer `$(".sonicrow")` you reach to a node with "sonicrow" as a class name. Now you need to search the children nodes which is a div...

So your code will be something like this:

1. Find elements having "sonicrow" class name
2. Find any children element whose type is "div"...
3. Apply css

---

**Solution:**

Find a reference to the nodes having "sonicrow" as class name: `var route=$(".sonicrow");`

Find child nodes which is a div: `var desiredChild =  route.find("div");`

Apply css: `desiredChild.css("property","value");`...

---

**Merge this into jquery chain:**

```
$(".sonicrow").find("div").css('background-color', 'red');
```

But you want to repeat this for every element which has "sonicrow" class name, so you have to loop and your code becomes:

```
$(".sonicrow").each(function() 
{
    $(this).find("div").css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

P.S. I have used $(this) here because $(".sonicrow") has returned an object and you are traversing that particular object so you have to use `"this" variable` to point into that element.

On the other hand, you are using Jquery so $(this) gives you an jquery object to work this, otherwise you had to use basic javascript syntax like: `this.style.css.property=value` syntax :-)

I hope you have got your answer...