# How to get a Selector using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, this

I have a Selector in a Selector. I want the inner Selector to select only those elements, that are also selected by the outer Selector. 
This is what my naiveté came up with:

```
$('.some-class').hover(function() {
    $( this + '.another-class'); 
})
```

Put differently, I want the elements with with `another-class` AND which are children of the element that is hovering. How do I do that?

Comment: you could just pass `this` as a second parameter to `$`. Like: `$('.another-class', this);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`children()` method](http://api.jquery.com/children).

```
$('.some-class').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.another-class');
});
```

This method falls under the [traversal category](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), which allows you to select ancestors, descendants, siblings etc all from the current element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.some-class').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.another-class'); 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This Keyword represent Object

You need to try this

```
jQuery(".another-class", this);
```

More [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)

Comment: It should be noted that this is looking for descendants, not just children.