# Jquery animate single div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

I am using multiple instances of div class .item_wrap, which changes height when the image class .item is hovered over.

At the moment, the following script animates all instances of the div class on mouse hover. Is there a way to have only the current hovered div animate, without the rest animating at the same time? ^^;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").hover(
        function(){
            $('.item_wrap').animate({duration:'slow', easing:'easeOutBack', height:265 }, 500);
        },    
        function(){
            $('.item_wrap').stop().animate({duration:'slow', easing:'easeOutBack', height:200 }, 500);
        }
    );
});
```

the html:

```
<div class="item_wrap">
<a href="images/burgundyholographicgoldsequin.jpg" class="item"  title="image">
<img src="images/burgundyholographicgoldsequin.jpg" width="250" height="192" /></a>
<div class="item_text">Text here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each item has a similar relationship with item_wrap (e.g. item_wrap is the parent of each item) then you can use a selector relative to `this`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).parent('.item_wrap').animate({duration:'slow', easing:'easeOutBack', height:265 }, 500);
        },    
        function(){
            $(this).parent('.shopitem_wrap').stop().animate({duration:'slow', easing:'easeOutBack', height:200 }, 500);
        }
    );
});
```

This, ofcourse, depends on your HTML.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! :D Sorry, I really should have really posted the html when I first posted this. ^^;

Answer (score 0):

We would need to know the html of your page, but in general if we assume that

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item_wrap"></div>
</div>
```

then i would change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".item").hover( function(){
$(this).children('.item_wrap').animate({duration:'slow', easing:'easeOutBack', height:265 }, 500);
},    
function() {
$('.shopitem_wrap').stop().animate({duration:'slow', easing:'easeOutBack', height:200 }, 500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if we could see some of your html, but you want to use `this` with your `.itemwrap div`

For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".item").hover( function(){
$('.item_wrap', this).animate({duration:'slow', easing:'easeOutBack', height:265 }, 500);
},    
function() {
$('.shopitem_wrap', this).stop().animate({duration:'slow', easing:'easeOutBack', height:200 }, 500);
});
});
```

This link has a similar question: [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)