# How do I select the last element with a specified class from descendants of this?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a `<div>` with many `<ul>` descendants with different classes, and I am calling a function on this `<div>` which modifies the last `<ul>` with a given class. How do I select the last `<ul>` descendant with a specified class using `$(this)` jQuery selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method:

```
var last = $(this).find("ul.someClass").last();
```

Or the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector:

```
var last = $(this).find("ul.someClass:last");
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I will try it out :).

Comment: You can also read about alternate ways to select child elements at http://stackoverflow.com/a/306904/896341

Answer (score 0):

i think it should work also.

```
var uls = $(this).find("ul.someClass")

var lastUl = uls[uls.length - 1];
```

Comment: It would, but `length` is a property, not a method. `size` is a method though, so you could use that.