# Show absolutely pos. div on hover in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, fade, absolute

I have a simple question yet it's not working out. See this html:

```
<div id="viewer">
    <ul class="tj_gallery">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/projecten/main/chicane.png" alt="" width="280" height="178" /></a><a href="#" class="abhover">01</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The `a.abhover` is absolutely positioned inside the relative `li`. The `a.abhover` has `display:none;` in CSS. If I hover one `li` (it's a long list!) the a.abhover should fadeIn @ 1000ms. Right now this is working, but only for every single one of those li's. See my jQuery code:

```
$(".tj_gallery li").hover(function(){
    $(".tj_gallery li a.abhover").stop(true,true).fadeIn("fast");   
}, function(){
    $(".tj_gallery li a.abhover").stop(true,true).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Adding `$(this, ".tj_gallery li a.abhover")` or `$(".tj_gallery li a.abhover", this)` doesn't help (it breaks it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".tj_gallery li").hover(function(){
    $("a.abhover", this).stop(true,true).fadeIn("fast");
}, function(){
    $("a.abhover", this).stop(true,true).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works and mine not? I should only use the last child of the html structure? Thanks by the way!

Comment: `$("a.abhover", this)` here you work only with hovered `$(".tj_gallery li")`, and in your example you work with all `$(".tj_gallery li a.abhover")` together.

Comment: You are welcome. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children