# How to get hidden td value from a table?

Tags: jquery

I have a table of this format.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td class="divOne">div one</td>
     <td class="divOne">11111</td>
     <td style="visibility:hidden" class="divOne">id1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="divOne">div two</td>
     <td class="divOne">22222</td>
     <td style="visibility:hidden" class="divOne">id2</td>
  </tr></div>
  </table>
```

I have written a function to show another div on mouse over.

```
$(function() {
  $('.divOne').hover(function() { 
  $('#Details').show(); 
}, function() { 
  $('#Details').hide(); 
});
});
```

Now I need to get the 'id' value on mouse over.
 I tried this function, but it returns a null value...

```
$(function(){
$('.divOne').hover(function(){
  var id = $(this).find('td.hidden').html();
  alert(id);
});
});
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Can you use hiddenfield [`<input type="hidden"`] instead of `hidden <td>` ? If yes, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817041/jquery-to-get-hidden-field-value-in-table-row

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Explanation

I think the others are making it too difficult for you.

The problem with your code is that you're attempting to find a `td` within a `td`.
When you do `$(this)` within the context of an event function, it refers to the element whose event was triggered.

```
$('.divOne').hover(function(){
    $(this); //<- "this" refers to the current "divOne" the user is hovering.
    // ".divOne" or $(this) is a td
    $(this).find("td.hidden"); //<- Attempts to find a td with the class "hidden" within ".divOne"
});
```

However, if you'd use the proper tree traversal function [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and the pseudo class [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) you'd be successful in your endeavor.

```
$('.divOne').hover(function(){
   var id = $(this).siblings(":hidden").html();
});
```

That would give you all the `td`s that are hidden. Since your example only had one column that was hidden, it should suffice.

If you'd want a specific sibling you could either add a class or use a combo `:nth-child(n):hidden`.

```
$('.divOne').hover(function(){
   var id = $(this).siblings(".myclass:hidden").html();
});
```

---

### Example

The easiest way to grab the id of the third, and last, `td` is by using either of the pseudo-classes

- [`:nth-child(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)
- [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

You could also define your own class, like `myclass` and then do

```
$("td.myclass")
```

[Here's a working JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/63wuB/1/) | Code

```js
$('table tr').hover(
    function(){
        var id = $("td:nth-child(3)", this).text();
        //var id = $("td:last-child", this).text();
        //var id = $("td.myclass", this).text();

        $("#Details").html("Details box.<br /> Hovering \""+id+"\"");
        $("#Details").show();
    }, function() {
        $('#Details').hide();
    }
);
```

Notice the use of the selector, where I instead use `table tr` so that the events only need to be triggered once you hover in and out a table row. This also enables me to use a context reference. Now `$(this)` refers to the row the user is hovering, and all its children (`td`s) are within it.

I also use a [selector with a second parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children), defining the context of my selection. By default it is the entire document.

This limits the selection to the element the user is hovering and its children. Err... by that, I mean not the *users* children, but the element's children.

```
$("td:nth-child(3)", this)
```

equals to: `find the third table division within this row I'm hovering`

---

### References

- [JQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [Using a second parameter in JQuery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)
- [Pseudo-classes](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclasses)

  - [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)
  - [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)
  - [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)
- [Tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

  - [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: +1 only because unable to +2. Very helpful review/summary of selectors, pseudo-classes and tree traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using inline css "visibility:hidden", add a class to that object called "hidden", and in your .css file add:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;    
}
```

This will make your code work ( I think ), and also make your mark-up look much better.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`, use a filter (*Edit:* as Crab Bucket noted, find search only descendants, when what you want are the siblings):

```
var id = $(this).siblings().filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("visibility") === "hidden";
}).html();
```

AFAIK there's not direct way of doing using only selectors. (you *could* check the "style" attribute and do a partial match, but that breaks if the style property comes from a class or css file)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the jQuery attribute selector and the ".nextAll()" traversing method, assumed that the "id"-column is the only hidden column.
Try the following:

```
$(function(){
  $('.divOne').hover(function(){
    var id = $(this).nextAll('td[visibility="hidden"]').text();
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

Edit: Corrected selector, thx to @mgibsonbr for mentioning that ":hidden" selector doesn't cover visibility attribute

Comment: According to the [api docs](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/), elements with `visibility:hidden` are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` function works on the descendants so `$(this).find` won't find the hovered element
Try

```
if($(this).has('.hidden'))
{
  var id = $(this).html();
}
```

Comment: How exactly is this going to work if the element is hidden and the hover events won't fire because it is in fact hidden? If you ask me, this is a "syntactically" null statement. :P

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate class for your hidden td tags:
class="divOne hidden".
Now do the following

```
$(function(){
    $('.divOne').hover(function(){
    var id11 = $('.hidden')[0];
    id1 = $(id11).html();
    var id22 = $('.hidden')[1];
    id2 = $(id22).html();
    alert(id1 + "  " + id2);
    });
});
```