# reversing the jquery fade slide panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, panel, slide, visible

Regarding the post about the jquery fade slide panel (http://stackoverflow.com/q/10061847/1688202).

I was wondering if the method could be reserved? So that the content panel will be standard visible and when clicked on disappear.

It tried to change some variable in the JQuery code, but I did not manage to successfully do this.

The code below has been written by **Shef** (http://stackoverflow.com/users/645186/shef)

**SOLVED BY BATMAN**

```
.panel.default {
    display:block;
}
.panel.default .content{
    display:block;
}
```

to the CSS, and add the class default to the panel you want to show when you load the page, e.g.

```
<div class="panel home default">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nhEn6/

#### 1. CSS

```
div.panel {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:70%;
    right:0%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:black;
}
.panel div.content {
    display:none;
    font-family:arial;
    color:white;
    padding:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
span.close {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}​
```

#### 2. Markup

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="about-me" href="#">About Me</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panels">
    <div class="panel home">
        <div class="content">
            <span class="close">X</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id ligula elit, vitae tincidunt massa. Vestibulum quis tempus lectus. Vestibulum diam dolor, tristique eget tincidunt eu, posuere nec nulla. Nulla a sollicitudin diam. Nunc venenatis dui in turpis ultricies semper. Nulla justo nibh, volutpat nec rutrum id, viverra ac nulla. Maecenas elit felis, rhoncus sit amet imperdiet eget, ultricies ut lorem. Praesent sed felis diam</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel about-me">
        <div class="content">
            <span class="close">X</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id ligula elit, vitae tincidunt massa. Vestibulum quis tempus lectus. Vestibulum diam dolor, tristique eget tincidunt eu, posuere nec nulla. Nulla a sollicitudin diam. Nunc venenatis dui in turpis ultricies semper. Nulla justo nibh, volutpat nec rutrum id, viverra ac nulla. Maecenas elit felis, rhoncus sit amet imperdiet eget, ultricies ut lorem. Praesent sed felis diam</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### 3. jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $panels = $('.panels > .panel');
    $('#menu > li').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $panels.filter('.'+this.id).trigger('togglePanel');
    });
    $panels
        .on('togglePanel', function(){
            var $this           =   $(this)
              , $activePanels   =   $panels.filter(':visible').not($this);
            if ($activePanels.length) {
                $activePanels
                    .one('panelHidden', function(){
                        $this.is(':visible')
                        ? $this.trigger('hidePanel')
                        : $this.trigger('showPanel');
                    })
                    .trigger('hidePanel');
            } else {
                $this.is(':visible')
                ? $this.trigger('hidePanel')
                : $this.trigger('showPanel');
            }
        })
        .on('hidePanel', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.find('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $this.animate({
                    'width': 'hide'
                }, 1000, function(){
                    $this.trigger('panelHidden');
                });
            });
        })
        .on('showPanel', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.animate({
                'width': 'show'
            }, 1000, function() {
                $this.find('.content').fadeIn(500, function(){
                    $this.trigger('panelShown');
                });
            });
        });
    $panels.find('.content .close').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.panel').trigger('togglePanel');
    });
});​
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
.panel.default {
    display:block;
}
.panel.default .content{
    display:block;
}
```

to the CSS, and add the class `default` to the panel you want to show when you load the page, e.g. `<div class="panel home default">`

http://jsfiddle.net/nhEn6/

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
style="display:block;"
```

inline to your html elements which you want to show by default.

You need to add this to both `panel` and `content` classes.