# giving attributes to all imgs in a div

Tags: jquery, children

I want all the images in a div to have a certain margin property, I can't quite seem to get it to work, this is what I've tried,

```
$("#images > img").each(function(){
    $(img).css({
      margin-top:15px;
      margin-bottom:15px;
});
});
```

thanks for any help

```
$("#pt_figures").click(function() {

$('#images').empty();

$('#images').css({
paddingLeft: 150,
paddingRight: 0
});
$('#controls').css({
width:700,
marginLeft:150
});
$('#info').css({
width:660,
marginLeft:150
```

});

var id = $(this).attr('id');

$("#info_header").load(id +"_header.txt");
   $("#content_1").load(id +"_1.txt");
   $("#content_2").load(id +"_2.txt");
   $("#content_3").load(id +"_3.txt");

```
$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figures_doc.jpg" }).appendTo("#images"); 
$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figure_front.png" }).appendTo("#images"); 
$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figure_back.jpg" }).appendTo("#images");


$("#images img").addClass("images");

$("#top_section").animate({
    height: 3780
}, 300);
$("#grid").animate({
    marginTop: 3780 + 300,
    paddingBottom: 300
}, 300); 


});
```

Comment: Why not just do this with CSS?

Comment: how would you do it with css?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: just realized also, the properties should be listed marginTop:15, marginBottom:15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommended practice is surely to add a class which defines the properties you require rather than write CSS directly in your jQuery code.

**Javascript:**

```
$("#images img").addClass("myClass");
```

**CSS:**

```
.myClass {
   margin:15px 0;
}
```

Alternatively, just define your properties in your CSS and don't use jQuery.

**CSS:**

```
#images img {
   margin:15px 0;
}
```

Comment: can I ask why writing a class is better just out of curiosity?

Comment: also the images are being added dynamically and doing it through pure css doesn't seem to get applied for some reason, I'm not sure why?

Comment: Much easier to maintain a stylesheet rather than css directly inside your jQuery. I seem to remember reading that it's better for performance/speed too.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem on jsfiddle.net or provide a link to your site?

Comment: any idea on why doing it with pure css doesn't work with dynamically added content?  Would it have to be bound after being added with javascript?

Comment: @loriensleafs - I don't think so. As I said, if you can recreate the problem on jsfiddle.net or provide a link to your site that would let us see your problem.

Comment: yes! Sorry I for some reason just didn't see that, I added the js to the top and the url is www.klossal.com .  If you click on the bottom left image you can see how the script works.  I added your function into the script so it's applying the css that way, it doesn't seem to work just in the style sheet.

Comment: Which images should the css be applied to? The 7 thumnail images at the bottom of the page or the ones that appear when you click the thumbnail?

Comment: the ones that appear when you click the thumbnail

Comment: If you use Firebug you'll be able to see that the css is being applied to those images. ".images { margin:15px 0; }"

Comment: yea so for those it is because I added into the function that animates to $("#images img").addClass("myClass");  if I take it out it doesn't add it.  I took out that line of jquery, now it's not applying it anymore.  You can see now that it doesn't work w/ just CSS.

Comment: Okay, so just change your CSS to apply to the images now that they don't have that class applied: #images img { margin:15px 0; }

Comment: ....I'm not sure why that was so hard for me to wrap my head around, haha thanks for sticking with me on that....

Answer (score 4):

use  [`$(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)

```
 $("#images > img").each(function(){
        $(this).css({
          margin-top:15px;
          margin-bottom:15px;
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#images > img").each(function(){
    $(this).css({
      margin-top:15px;
      margin-bottom:15px;
});
});
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#images img").each(function(){
    $(this).css({
        margin-top:15px;
        margin-bottom:15px;
    });
});
```

You are using $(img) but that has no context. Use $(this) instead. Also I removed the > from your selector in case the IMG tags are not a direct descendent of the DIV.

Comment: thanks, it's always great when people give explanations like that. I didn't realize the > had that implication.

Answer (score 1):

This may aswell be done in pure css.

```
#images > img { // ">" means direct child, remove it if necesarry
  margin: 15px 0; // shorthand for top/bottom: 15px and right/left: 0px
}
```

`>` means direct child, which means only images that are children of #images will be affected, "grandchildren" and further will not be. If you intend them to be affected, remove the `>`

Comment: so the images are being added dynamically and doing it through css that way doesn't seem to get applied.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(img)` to `$(this)` and it should be good to go.

`$(this)` is the current object in the each loop.

You may be able to apply `$("#images > img").css(...)` as well, as I don't see directly why you need to loop through them all.