# jQuery selector with $(this) as an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css-selectors

I have found this form of selector inside a plugin, can anyone explain it to me?

```
var container = $(this);
var myDiv = $('div', container);
```

The idea is to only select the `div` element, why would it have the `container` variable as well?

Comment: Martlark, Matías and PSCoder, thanks a bunch ! Now I get it !

Comment: You are welcome! You should mark one of our answers as the accepted one if you feel that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is he context of the selector, it's like doing a `.find()`

EXAMPLE:

```
$("#selector", context) = $(context).find("#selector")
```

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer appears to address your requirements for an explanation.
[How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children).  Essentially: The jQuery constructor accepts a 2nd parameter which can be used to override the context of the selection.