# Target only a certain instance of a <div> within an array with JQuery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

What I am trying to achieve is to have a responsive horizontal and vertical slider for use with my portfolio. The issue arises where I have an array of `<div>`s all with class 'project. I cannot seem to target a specific instance of each `<div>`, even when the element with the click event is within the element to be targeted.

To explain visually: When a user clicks on the 'right' arrow, the JQuery should calculate the number of `<img>`s in the instance of the clicked arrow and cycle through them. The error seems to come where the JQuery is currently checking the total images in all `<div class=project">`s. You can see a live example here:

http://yaocho-digital.com/portfolio/

Here is my JQuery, so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    // Get amount of projects

    var projectTotal = $('.project').length;

    // Get window height

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    // Create 'clickCounter' variable, so as not to go over the project amount, set at 1 to reflect 'nth-child' value of projects created before

    var clickCounter = 1;

    // Animate each window height on 'down' click

    $('.down').click(function() {
         $('.container').animate({top: '-=' + windowHeight}, 'fast');
         clickCounter = clickCounter + 1;
         if (clickCounter > projectTotal) {
            $('.container').animate({top: '0'}, 'fast');
            clickCounter = 1;
         }
    });

    // Hide all images

    $('.project > img').hide();

    // Get the amount of images in each project

    var imageTotal = $('.project > img').length;

    // Set the initial image at one, not zero, so that the variable can control 'nth-child'

    var imageCounter = 1;

    // Show first <img> of each project

    $('.project > img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')').show();

    // Set variable for retrieving parent of clicked 'next'

    var parentElement = $(this).parent();

    $('.next').click(function() {
        $('' + parentElement + ' > img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')').hide();
        $('' + parentElement + ' > img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')').next().show();
        imageCounter = imageCounter + 1;
        if (imageCounter > imageTotal) {
            imageCounter = 1;
            $('' + parentElement + ' > img').hide();
            $('' + parentElement + ' > img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')').show();
        }
        console.log($(this).parent());
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to this, incase anyone has the same issue:

```
// Hide all images

    $('div.project > img').hide();

    // Get the amount of images in each project

    var imageTotal = $(this).find('div.project > img').size();

    // Set the initial image at one, not zero, so that the variable can control 'nth-child'

    var imageCounter = 1;

    // Show first <img> of each project

    $('div.project > img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')').show();

    // Initiate carousel on 'next'

    $('a.next').click(function() {
        imageCounter = imageCounter + 1;
        $(this).parent().find('img').hide();
        $(this).parent().find('img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')').show();
        if (imageCounter > imageTotal) {
            imageCounter = 1;
            $(this).parent().find('img').hide();
            $(this).parent().find('img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')').show();
        }
        console.log(imageCounter);
        console.log(imageTotal);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children) SO question.
Your "parentElement" object is returning an object and not an element name (as your are assuming), so there is an error being thrown:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] > img:nth-child(1)

Try using:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $('img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')', parentElement).hide();
    $('img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')', parentElement).next().show();
    imageCounter = imageCounter + 1;
    if (imageCounter > imageTotal) {
        imageCounter = 1;
        $('img', parentElement).hide();
        $('img:nth-child(' + imageCounter + ')', parentElement).show();
    }
    console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

Comment: This still returns an object and won't play ball!