# How do I access the elements that are inside the 'this' that I am currently working with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

How do I access the elements that are inside the 'this' that I am currently working with ?

Following is the HTML code I am currently working with.

```
<div class="expander" id="edu">educational qualifications
             <ul class="list">
                 <li>bachelor's in cs</li>
                 <li><div  class="expander">master's in machine learning
                     <ul class="list" id="edu1">
                         <li>authored the famous paper on giving a shit</li>
                         <li>co-authored several other papers</li>
                     </ul></div>
                 </li>
                 <li><div class="expander">phd in visual intelligence
                     <ul class="list">
                         <li>watch and learn</li>
                         <li>haha.</li>
                     </ul></div>
                 </li>
                 <li>cleared jee mains</li>
                 <li>cleared cbse aissce</li>
             </ul></div>
```

I was experimenting with my new found knowledge of Javascript and I wanted to make it such that all the bullet points would be hidden until I hovered over their headings.
I tried to use the following javascript code for that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('li ul').hide();
$('.expander').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this + 'ul').fadeIn('fast');
}); });
```

I'm not able to get it to work. How do I access the elements that are inside the 'this' that I am currently working with ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(this) selector and children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)

Comment: change + to , it suppose to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this -

```
$('ul',this).fadeIn('fast');
```

**Edit** -

```
$('.expander ul').hide();
$('.expander').mouseenter(function () {
    $('ul:first',this).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/jahR6/

Comment: I did this but this reveals all of the bullet points, even those that are placed in another <ul>.

Comment: Thanks!
This works!
But I don't think it would work in case I had three levels of nesting of the <ul>s.

Answer (score 1):

Variant #1:

```
$('ul', this).fadeIn('fast');
```

Variant #2:

```
$(this).find('ul').fadeIn('fast');
```

They are equivalent.

Comment: I'd go for the context rather than `find`. It's one less function call, and less code.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer less code - yes, less function call - no. Internally jQuery will use find anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).find('ul').fadeIn('fast');
```