# How to select all item expect item in specific class

Tags: jquery, selector

I have recursive HTML, I know ID of outer most DIV. In below HTML i want to select all DIV with class "citem" expect "citem" inside inner "Popup"

```
<div id="pop1" class="Popup">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="citem">child item-1</div>

        <div class="Popup">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="citem">child inner item-1</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="citem">child item-2</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof $ != "undefined") {
        $(function () {

            var Parent = $("#pop1");
            var Container = $(Parent.find(".container:first"));

            Container.find(".citem").not(".Popup .citem").each(function () {
                alert($(this).html());
            });

        });
    }
</script>
```

Using above code no item is selected, but i want output to be "child item-1" and "child item-2".

Any idea, what how to write query for this. i don't want to select all item and then check who is parent etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your main parent element has a class of `"Popup"` which disqualifies all `citem`s

```
<div id="pop1" class="Popup">
```

so

```
Container.find(".citem").not(".Popup .Popup .citem").each(function () {
```

should work

Comment: Is there any way to use "this" keyword in JQuery selector ? so that we can say select all item expect current item ?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children

Comment: or something like `$('.class').not($(this).find('.class'))`, or `$('.class').not($(this))`, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The > selector will only catch the first level children.

```
jQuery('.container > .citem')
```

Will not match an item with class .citem unless his parent has class .container.