# Access element through this -> class selector

Tags: jquery

If I want to access a div with class `ccc` withing div with ID `iii`, I can do

```
$('#iii .ccc').doStuff();
```

But how do I access a div with class `ccc` within `this` div?

`$('this .ccc').doStuff()` doesn't seem to work. The context I'm trying to use it in is as follows:

```
$('.substitute').each(function () {
    if (some condition) {
        $('this .subcaptain').addClass('team_captain');
    }
    cnt++;
});
```

"some condition" is met (tested by logging to console) but the `team-captain` class isn't assigned.

The HTML is a bunch of DIVs with the following structure:

```
<div class='substitute'>
    <div class='subcaptain'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(this).find('.ccc').doStuff()
```

or

```
$('.ccc',this).find('.ccc').doStuff()
```

Comment: `$('this')` wouldn't this (try to) select an element with tagName `this` ?

Comment: Also, isn't `$('.ccc',this)` equal to `$(this)` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: No it is not. it find the element from first selector within element in second selector.The jQuery constructor accepts a 2nd parameter which can be used to override the context of the selection.

Comment: Neither of those works for me. Any idea why that could be? The inside elements definitely exist. The inside one (with class `ccc`) is a span, not a div - though I doubt that should matter.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Interesting! I didn't know this.

Comment: @jovan Share a fiddle if it matters please.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work, thank you both. I will accept the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @GaurangTandon: yes that is confusing and looks wrong as we are used to single selector. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/306904/1719752