# jquery / comparing dates in list

Tags: jquery, date, compare

I have been trying to solve this issue for two days. Maybe someone has a hint for me?

I have this couple of divs and in every `div.news-list-item` are 2 dates - `startdate` and `enddate`. I want to compare the two dates to check if they are equal. If they are equal then add the class `show`, if not do something else.

The Problem is that `startDate` is always empty or undefined.

```
<div class="news-list-container row">   
    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-1">
        <span class="event-from">17.10.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">19.10.2014</span>
    </div>

    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-2">
        <span class="event-from">07.12.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">07.12.2014</span>
    </div>

    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-3">
        <span class="event-from">08.12.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">08.12.2014</span>
    </div>   
</div>



$('.news-list-container').each(function() {
    var $children = $(this).children(),
        count = $children.size(),
        $item;
        $children.each(function(i) {
            $item = $(this).addClass('nth-item-' + (i + 1))

});

$(".news-list-item").each(function() {
    var startDate =  $(".event-from").val();
    var endDate = $(".event-to").val();

        if(startDate == endDate) {
                $(this).addClass("show");       
            } else {

            }
    }); 
    console.log("story " + startDate + " story");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use `find` relative to the current `$(this)`
- use `text` to retrieve text content

Here a working live sample:

```js
$('.news-list-container').each(function() {
    var $children = $(this).children(), count = $children.size(), $item;
    $children.each(function(i) {
        $item = $(this).addClass('nth-item-' + (i + 1))
    });

    $(this).find(".news-list-item").each(function() {
        var startDate = $(this).find(".event-from").text();
        var endDate = $(this).find(".event-to").text();

        if(startDate == endDate) {
            $(this).show();       
        } else {
            $(this).hide(); 
        }
        console.log("story " + startDate + " story");
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-list-container row">   
    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-1">
        <span class="event-from">17.10.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">19.10.2014</span>
    </div>

    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-2">
        <span class="event-from">07.12.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">07.12.2014</span>
    </div>

    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-3">
        <span class="event-from">08.12.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">08.12.2014</span>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: This is a perfect example how to do it. I made two small modifications but it's not worth telling because I didnt described it in my question. Thanks a lot Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) of `this` to the $(".event-from") and  $(".event-to") to get the child divs.

Additionally spans do not have val() but text()

```
var startDate =  $(".event-from",this).text();
var endDate = $(".event-to",this).text();
```

which is the same as

```
$(this).find("span.event-from")...
```

More here: [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)

My example

```js
$(function() {
  $(".news-list-container > .news-list-item").each(function() {
    var startDate = $(".event-from",this).text();
    var endDate   = $(".event-to",this).text();
    $(this).toggle(startDate != endDate);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-list-container row">   
    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-1">
        <span class="event-from">17.10.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">19.10.2014</span>
    </div>

    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-2">
        <span class="event-from">07.12.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">07.12.2014</span>
    </div>

    <div class="news-list-item nth-item-3">
        <span class="event-from">08.12.2014</span>
        <span class="event-to">08.12.2014</span>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(function(){

    $('.news-list-item').each(function() {

        if($('.event-from', this).text() == $('.event-to', this).text()) {

           $(this).addClass('show);

        } else {

            console.log('Not Equal');
        }

    });

});
```