# How to check if a specific div element is created or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if following code is dynamically created or not :

```
<div id="js_contact_error_message" style="display: block;">
  <div class="error_message"> <!-- For this div only I want to apply the above written inline css-->
              Please enter full name
  </div>
```

How should I check this in jQuery? If it's present execute the if condition.

Thanks.

The condition that `<div class="error_message">...</div>` is present within `<div id="js_contact_error_message" style="display: block;">...</div>` must get checked.

I tried below code but it didn't work for me:

```
if ($("#js_contact_error_message").find("div.error_message").length != 0) { 
          alert("Bestow");
      }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(this) selector and children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

For using `if-else` condition.

```
if($("#js_contact_error_message").find(".error_message").length > 0)
{
    alert("div present");
}
else
{
    alert("div not present");
}
```

But as you stated in your question, you want to apply specific inline css. Make a class for the style what you have and you can use the ollowin code.

```
$("#js_contact_error_message").find(".error_message").addClass("your_style_class");
```

This code will apply your css class only for those `div`s which match the condition.

**EDIT:**

If you want to add your style to the `div`, you can try defining it in your page, which will apply as soon as the div is added dynamically.

```
<style>
    #js_contact_error_message .error_message
    {
         /*your inline style*/
    }
</style>
```

Comment: As the <div class="error_message"> <!-- For this div only I want to apply the above written inline css-->
              Please enter full name
  </div> is getting created dynamically length property is not working.

Comment: if length is not working then you may be calling it in a wrong place.

Comment: @PHPNut when is your dynamic `div` gettin created?

Comment: After form submission.

Comment: @phpnut do you have css class with the name `error_message` in your current page?

Comment: When the page loads it doesn't. When the pop-up loads still it doesn't. When the user submits form then the div with class name error_message gets created. If I check length on form submit I get 0 since the div has yet to be created. This is the issue.

Comment: @PHPNut no, not that, I am asking do you have defined style with the class name `error_message`?

Comment: This class is getting applied to the div when it gets created. The file containing the class error_message has already been added.

Comment: @PHPNut do you have style defenition for that class? in style sheets or in style tag? Try my edited code, and remove all above `jquery` code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var hasDiv = $("#js_contact_error_message div").length > 0 ? true : false;

$("#js_contact_error_message").toggle(hasDiv);
```

---

#### Note:

You need to place this line of code where you have done your js validations.

---

or you may try with this:

```
$(document).on('DOMSubTreeModified propertychange',function(){
     var hasDiv = $("#js_contact_error_message div").length > 0 ? true : false;
     $("#js_contact_error_message").toggle(hasDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#js_contact_error_message .error_message").length > 0)
{
    alert("div is present");
}
else
{
    alert("div is not present");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t4dnppe0/1/)**

Comment: The length property will not work since the <div class="error_message"> <!-- For this div only I want to apply the above written inline css--> Please enter full name </div> is getting generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in many ways.. few of them are :

1. Use `$("#js_contact_error_message").has('div')` function of jquery to get the specific element [Has in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/has/)
2. If the error message div is the only div to be inside the main div then you can check it as :

Check the element `$("#js_contact_error_message").html()` is blank or use `$("#js_contact_error_message").children()` ([Children in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/children/)) to check if it has any childrens.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure your html composition is correct ,  opening and closing. Then try this code.

```
if($("#js_contact_error_message").length > 0)
{
  $("#js_contact_error_message").find(".error_message").addClass("style_class");
}
```