# Chose one from same divs on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Have a problem that can not solve (I'm new in jScript).

I have 3 rows, each contains 4 blocks, row in HTML below (bootstrap):

```
<div class="row product-element">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="product-element-container">
          <img src="img/1_mini.jpg" alt="Texto Alternativo 1" class="img-thumbnail">
          <h4>Some text H4</h4>
          <p>Some text p</p>
          <p>Some text p</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success launch-modal" data-modal-id="modal-register" data-img-url="img/1_mini.jpg" title="buy">BUY</a>
      </div>
...
...
...
</div>
```

I have also modal window, that opens when user click "buy" button, and I need to copy  and

elements from "product-element-container" to modal window.

Problem: I don't know how to create proper "select" in jQuery that will chose div with pressed button. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: are you looking for ? https://api.jquery.com/clone/ see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children  clone to copy part of html and send it into modal, so link if you want to select specific children

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks for reply. I've studied methods to copy information in divs, my weak point - selectors. Solution - siblings() method. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple implementation of what you're trying to do:

```
$('a.launch-modal').click(function() {
    var content = $(this).siblings('.product-element-container').html();
    $('#modal-register').html(content);
});
```

First, you add an on click event listener to all `<a class="launch-modal">` elements, the callback (i.e. what happens after you click) gets the HTML content of the corresponding `<div class="product-element-container">` element and puts it in the `<div id="modal-register>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).siblings('.product-element-container')` within your button click event callback function.

Answer (score 0):

First give classes to h4 and your p tags inside the container that you want to copy.

Second add an attribute such as data- btnId="button id here" to the button.

Next bootstrap have a event on modal open show.bs.modal and shown.bs.modal which fires on opening and after modal is being rendered on page respectively.

```
   $( '#your modal id" ).on
    ('show.bs.modal' , function
    (event) {
    var button =
    $(event.relatedTarget) //  Button that triggered the modal
     var recipient = button.data
   ('btn id here which is inside container' ) //   Extract info  from data-* attributes

    var modal = $( this)
    modal.find( "h4").text( receipt.   parent(".    containerClassNameHereWhoseContentToBeCopied").   find("h4.classNameOfH4TagHereWhich.   IsInsideContainer).text());

    // Do same for P tags.
 })
```

Note* your modal should have h4 and p tags. Or you can put values/text to any tag.