# How to fix this in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 3 x 4 cards, it's a memory game. So to able to play, you need to guess 2 matches.

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
  $('.front').toggle();
  $('.back').toggle();
});
```

```css
.card .back {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  margin: 8px;
}

.card .front {
  background-color: blue;
}

.back,
.front {
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

.card .back {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card" id="dog">
      <div class="front">
        image here
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        back card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card" id="cat">
      <div class="front">
        image here
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        back card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card" id="dog">
      <div class="front">
        image here
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        back card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card" id="cat">
      <div class="front">
        image here
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        back card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Based from the snippet, if I click a one card, all of the cards flipped, which is wrong.

Now my problem is, how do I fix this through jquery?

Comment: That is what you wrote. Class selects all the elements with that class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is that you're targeting every single element with the class `front` and `back`, because of your selectors (`.front` and `.back`).

To fix this, you need to tell jQuery that you're targeting only the elements within the element the user just clicked, and for that you use the `find` function. This makes sure that jQuery checks just the elements in the one you target in and not every single element in the document.

So, where you wrote:

```
$('.card').click(function(){
    $('.front').toggle();
    $('.back').toggle();
});
```

You need to change it to

```
$('.card').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.front').toggle();
    $(this).find('.back').toggle();
});
```

Simple as that.

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.front').toggle();
  $(this).find('.back').toggle();
});
```

```css
.card .back {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  margin: 8px;
}

.card .front {
  background-color: blue;
}

.back,
.front {
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

.card .back {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card" id="dog">
      <div class="front">
        image here
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        back card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card" id="cat">
      <div class="front">
        image here
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        back card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card" id="dog">
      <div class="front">
        image here
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        back card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card" id="cat">
      <div class="front">
        image here
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        back card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well explained answer, keep it up. I have added code snippet if you can always remove it

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **this** to select only some elements with this `class`. Try this `$(this).find(".front").toggle().`

Comment: You should add some explanation to answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.card').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.front').toggle();
    $(this).find('.back').toggle();
});
```

That's it

Comment: You should add some explanation to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$('.card').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.front').toggle();
        $(this).find('.back').toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You selected with jQuery all the `.front` and all `.back`classes,  you should use that :

```
$('.card').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this); 
    $this.find('.front').toggle();
    $this.find('.back').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply** [*Read Here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306904/3385827)

```
$('.front , .back' , this).toggle();
```

```js
$('.card').click(function(){
  $('.front , .back' , this).toggle();
});
```

```css
.card .back{
display:none;
}

.card {
margin:8px;
}

.card .front{
background-color: blue;
}
.back, .front{
color:white;
width:100px;
height:150px;
}

.card .back{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card" id="dog">
       <div class="front">
        image here
       </div>
       <div class="back">
        back card
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card" id="cat">
       <div class="front">
        image here
       </div>
       <div class="back">
        back card
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card" id="dog">
       <div class="front">
        image here
       </div>
       <div class="back">
        back card
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card" id="cat">
       <div class="front">
        image here
       </div>
       <div class="back">
        back card
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$('.card').click(function() {
  $('.front').toggle();
  $('.back').toggle();
});
```

You attach a click listener to all elements with class `card`. Inside, you toggle **all** elements with class `front` and `back`. You need to be toggling just the `front` and `back` that are inside the clicked card. `$(this).find(".front").toggle();` does just that.