# How to selected a div inside a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select the div `nameMachine` using `this.`but I can't find how to select it:
[image]

I can get this element with this code :

```
$(".switch").each(function(){
   console.log(this);
   $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'white',
      'border-style': 'solid',
      'border-color': 'inherit',
      'border-width': '3px',
   });
});
```

Comment: add the rendered HTML not the image of the html

Comment: `this.querySelector('#nameMachine')`

Comment: try `$(this).find("#nameMachine").css({})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/how-to-get-the-children-of-the-this-selector

Comment: $(this).find('#nameMachine');

Comment: @Chinito you were  the first who answered and it works, so you can put an answer

Comment: Firstly, that element has an `id` so DOM traversal is redundant - just use that id. Secondly I'd suggest you familiarise yourself with the methods jQuery has, as this is a very basic request which you should be able to research yourself: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: @Jerome i already posted it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think I should gave more details because I need this redundant and I don't want to modify the part who change the css I just wanted to get the name to make something else after

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".switch").each(function(){
   console.log(this);
   $(this).find('#nameMachine').css({
      'background-color': 'white',
      'border-style': 'solid',
      'border-color': 'inherit',
      'border-width': '3px',
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find()

```
$(".switch").each(function(){
   console.log(this);
   $(this).find('#nameMachine').css({
      'background-color': 'white',
      'border-style': 'solid',
      'border-color': 'inherit',
      'border-width': '3px',
   });
});
```

You can use `children()` as well, but then you would need to go through those children and search for the one with the id `nameMachine`

Third, you can use `first()`, this will take the first child. However, this one is a little tricky since you have to make sure that your wanted div is always first.

Comment: '#nameMachine)  missing quotes

Comment: Thank you, @Sabrina

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".switch").each(function(){
     console.log(this);
     $(this).find('#nameMachine').css({
          'background-color': 'white',
          'border-style': 'solid',
          'border-color': 'inherit',
          'border-width': '3px',
     });
 });
```

or

```
$(".switch").each(function(){
     console.log(this);
     this.querySelector('#nameMachine').css({
          'background-color': 'white',
          'border-style': 'solid',
          'border-color': 'inherit',
          'border-width': '3px',
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.querySelector('#nameMachine');
```