# How to combine "this" with eq or x-child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to target the second child of the parent `foo`. How can I do that?

```js
$("#one").click(function() {
  // How to get "me" if I do not know the classname?
  // I need to target that second div (I know that it's second).
  var q = $(this).eq(1).attr('class');
  console.log(q); // undefined

  // Aim?
  // I need that element or classname
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="foo">
  <div>one</div>
  <div class="me"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/how-to-get-the-children-of-the-this-selector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the children first and then apply the [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
var q = $(this).children().eq(1).attr('class');
```

```js
$("#one").click(function() {

  var q = $(this).children().eq(1).attr('class');
  console.log(q); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="foo">
1
 <div></div>
 <div class="me"></div>
</div>
```

---

Or use the [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector as the argument of `children()` method.

```
var q = $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').attr('class');
```

```js
$("#one").click(function() {

  var q = $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').attr('class');
  console.log(q); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="foo">
1
 <div></div>
 <div class="me"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the second div

```
$(this).find('div:eq(1)').attr('class')
```

Comment: this may select the nested div, in case nested elements are there. So better to use `children` instead of `find`