# How to get a specific child of the $(this) selector (out of two children)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have already tried each of the solutions from: [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306583/4806162)

I have two buttons, one for Friday and one for Saturday. I want to only show the spinner icon on the button I clicked, not both buttons.

The two code attempts below do not produce any errors. They simply don't work.

```js
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(this).on('click', function(){
      $(this).children('.hide').toggleClass('.hide');
    });

  });

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn mb15 w100">
  <span class="button-text">Friday </span>
  <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-spin hide"></i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn mb15 w100">
  <span class="button-text">Saturday</span>
  <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-spin hide"></i>
</a>
```

```js
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(this).on('click', function(){
      $('.hide', this).toggleClass('.hide');
    });

  });

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn mb15 w100">
  <span class="button-text">Friday </span>
  <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-spin hide"></i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn mb15 w100">
  <span class="button-text">Saturday</span>
  <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-spin hide"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find spinner class on button click and remove `hide` class:

```
$('.waves-effect').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.fa-spin').removeClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is context based, you need to understand when to use it.

if you are unsure of the context of `this`, you can always use `console.log(this)`

here is a fix for your code:

```js
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.btn').on('click', function(){
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('hide');
    });

  });

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn mb15 w100">
  <span class="button-text">Friday </span>
  <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-spin hide"></i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn mb15 w100">
  <span class="button-text">Saturday</span>
  <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-spin hide"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply click events to the buttons instead of the document.

Comment: Isn't the click event applied to the element I clicked? I thought that `$(document).ready` was an okay wrapper for all of my jquery so that when the document is ready my functions will be usable.

Comment: Not when you are using this as a selector. See Major Allmightys answer, where he uses a class as selector :)

Comment: `this` doesn't work (pardon the pun) when I'm inside a `$(document).ready` wrapper?

Comment: @SpencerShattuck sure it does, but it's the document. (When you click *anything*, *everything* in the document is having `.hide` toggled)