# Get the id of the child div alone using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need the id of the child element alone which is clicked. If I use `$(this).attr('id')` it brings the id of the parent also.

Here is the code,

```
<body>
    <div id="divOne">
        <div id="divTwo">
            <div id="divThree">
                <div id="divFour">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I need the id of the div four alone when it is clicked

Comment: Show us your jquery code you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/how-to-get-the-children-of-the-this-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
console.log(event.target.id)
```

instead of

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

because `this` equals to element you bind on while `event.target` equals to the element triggered the event

Answer (score 1):

Use [`event.stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop the event from propagating to the parent `div`s:

```js
$('div').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOne">
  <div id="divTwo">
    <div id="divThree">
      <div id="divFour">
      test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation();` to stop propagating to the parent element:

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="divOne">
        <div id="divTwo">
            <div id="divThree">
                <div id="divFour">
                four
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**NOT WORKING EXAMPLE**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').click(function(event){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="divOne">
        <div id="divTwo">
            <div id="divThree">
                <div id="divFour">
                four
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

> **event.stopPropagation();** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("div").click(function(e) {
  console.log($(this).attr("id"));
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```