# Reference child element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following piece of code in order to add a class to an li item.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click', '.sidenav .page_item_has_children', function({
    $(this).addClass('side_open').siblings.removeClass('side_open')
})
```

As you can see It refers to the element that is clicked, in this instance an li. I need to apply this to the li's child element which is a ul so that the dropdown can appear. I assume I basically need something along the lines of the following however I can not work it out.

```
$(document).on('click', '.sidenav .page_item_has_children', function({
    $(child).addClass('side_open').siblings.removeClass('side_open')
})
```

If anyone has any ideas on how this can be done that would be great!

Thanks - Scott

Comment: If you could add sample markup with behavior, it would help

Comment: Why do you run the code in your function parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could try `jQuery(this).find('ul')` or `jQuery(this).children('ul');`

See also: [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/how-to-get-the-children-of-the-this-selector)

Use `$(this).find('ul');` to return all `ul` that are descendants of the `li` u referenced or `$(this).children('ul')` to find only 1st-level descendants.

Comment: Also what @Wimanicesir refers to is you seemingly forgot the closing bracket `)` to the [function parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)