# Attach (this) to secondary jquery element

Tags: jquery

I want to target the `.sf-input-checkbox` class in this instance. But my `(this)` is attached to the `.searchandfilter` instead.

```
$(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function(){
    if ( $('.sf-input-checkbox').is(":checked") ) {
    $(this).addClass('jordanchecked');
}
});
```

**Result currently:**

```
<div class="searchandfilter jordanchecked">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sf-input-checkbox">
</div>
```

I am after this:

```
<div class="searchandfilter">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sf-input-checkbox jordanchecked">
</div>
```

Comment: So target the checkbox, the same way you did in the if conditional. if statements don't change what `this` is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/how-to-get-the-children-of-the-this-selector)

Comment: `this` doesn't change in an `if` statement. You'll have to use a class selector. Or you could assign the selector to a variable outside the statement and use the variable inside the statement. Like: 
`$this = $('.example'); if ($this.is()) { $this.addClass(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have no relational link in your JS between the `this` of the event handler and the checkbox. That missing relationship is parent-child.

```
$(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function(){
    let cb = $(this).children('.sf-input-checkbox');
    if (cb.is(":checked")) cb.addClass('jordanchecked');
});
```