# Searching select option value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<select id = "tester" class = "tester">
   ...
   <option value = "code_2">2</option>
</select>

<select id = "tester" class = "tester">
   ...
   <option value = "code_2">2</option>
</select>
```

If `data` value is 2, I am trying to select every `tester` whereby their option value contains `2`.

```
$('.tester').each(function() {
   $(this option:contains(data)).prop("selected", true);
})
```

Selecting every `tester` was successful but failed to change its option value. what could be the reason?

Comment: May be same `id` is reason?

Comment: @EzioMercer If we have to select every `tester` then shouldn't we have to make id the same?

Comment: There must not be another element on the same page with the same id

Comment: You should use class multiple times not id

Comment: And can you please paste your code to publish place where we can run it? For example on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/)

Comment: The syntax `$(this option:contains(data))` is wrong.  There would be an error in the console.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/how-to-get-the-children-of-the-this-selector

Comment: @James Oh, syntax error was the cause. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

**HTML :**

```
<select class="tester" multiple>
    <option value="">N/A</option>
   <option value="code_2">2</option>
   <option value="code_2">2</option>
   <option value="code_2">2</option>
   <option value="code_2">2</option>
</select>

<select  class="tester" multiple>
   <option value="code_2">2</option>
   <option value="code_2">2</option>
   <option value="code_2">2</option>
   <option value="code_2">2</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript with Jquery**

```
var data = 2;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tester').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(i, element) {
        if($(element).text() == data){
            $(element).prop("selected", true)
        }
    });
})
});
```

NB: Don't use the same ID twice on the same page. To show multiple options selected. Use multiple Attribute on select tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code if you want to use jQuery:

```js
$('.tester').val('code_2').change();
```

Where:

`.tester` - is `select` selector

`code_2` - is `option` value

This code allows you to don't search `option` by yourself

Check the documentation [jQuery.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)